# Is there a solution for converting pre-built Angular2 apps to Electron.js?

Tags: angular, electron

I have a fairly complex application built on Angular2/Typescript and some other npm modules etc.

What i'm wondering is, is there an easy way to convert a webapp into and electron js app?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Electron should have no trouble loading an Angular front end strait up. It all depends what your after by using Electron. Sometimes all you need to do is load the externally hosted webapp url into a BrowserWindow. You can even have a hosted app detect that it is in Electron and offer added functionality.

Or are you after an offline experience? If so your biggest hurdle is not Angular, but bundling whatever is used for a backend.